# Handle errors from service in grails

Tags: grails, grails-validation

I have a problem with my code. How can I handle an error from service to my gsp? I tried it with render from service or controller, but instead something like **[Property [{0}] of class [{1}] with value [{2}] is not a valid e-mail address]** and got a **Error 500: Internal Server Error** with full exception trace. My sources:

**UserController.groovy**

```
def saveUser() {

    def salt = new SecureRandomNumberGenerator().nextBytes().getBytes()
    def user

    try {
        user = userService.registerMethod(params.username, params.passwordHash, params.passwordHash2,
            salt, params.firstName, params.lastName, params.sex, params.email, params.mobile, params.userType)

        session.user = user
        flash.message = "User ${user.profile.firstName} ${user.profile.lastName} was successfuly created!"
        redirect(uri:"/")
    } catch (UserRegistrationException ure) {
        user = ure.user
        if (user) {
            render(view:"registration",model:[user:user])
        } else {
            flash.message = ure.message
            redirect(action:"registration")
        }
    }

}
```

**UserService.groovy**

```
class UserRegistrationException extends RuntimeException {
String message
User user
}

class UserService {

boolean transactional = true

User registerMethod(String username, String password1, String password2, Object salt, String firstName, String lastName,
        String sex, String email, String mobile, String userType) {

    def user = User.findByUsername(username)
    if(user) {
        //flash.message = "User already exists with login ${username}"
        throw new UserRegistrationException(message:"User already exists with login ${username}")
        redirect(uri:"/")
    } else {
        if (password1 != password2) {
            //flash.message = "Passwords don't match"
            throw new UserRegistrationException(message:"Passwords don't match")
        } else {
            def profile = Profile.findByEmail(email)
            if (profile && (email == profile.email)) {
                //flash.message = "User with this email is already exists!"
                throw new UserRegistrationException(message:"User with this email is already exists!")
            } else {
                user = new User(
                    username:username,
                    passwordHash: new Sha512Hash(password1, salt, 1024).toHex(),
                    passwordSalt:salt,
                    profile: new Profile(
                        firstName:firstName,
                        lastName:lastName,
                        sex:sex,
                        email:email,
                        mobile:mobile,
                        userType:userType
                        )
                    )

                if (!user.hasErrors() && user.save(flush:true,failOnError:true)) {
                    def authToken = new UsernamePasswordToken(username, password1)
                    SecurityUtils.subject.login(authToken)
                    return user
                } else {
                    throw new UserRegistrationException(message:"Can't create user");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

**registration.gsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>Registration Page</h1>

    <g:if test="${ flash.message }">
        ${ flash.message }
    </g:if>
    <g:hasErrors bean="${ user }">
        <g:renderErrors bean="${ user }" as="list"/>
    </g:hasErrors>

    <div id="registration">
        <g:form action="saveUser">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="username">Login: </label></td>
                <td><g:textField name="username" id="username" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="firstName">First Name: </label></td>
                <td><g:textField name="firstName" id="firstName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="lastName">Last Name: </label></td>
                <td><g:textField name="lastName" id="lastName"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="sex">Sex: </label></td>
                <td><g:radioGroup values="['M','F']" name="sex" labels="['Male','Female']">
                <p>${ it.radio } ${ it.label }</p>
                </g:radioGroup></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="email">Email: </label></td>
                <td><g:textField name="email" id="email"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="mobile">Mobile: </label></td>
                <td><g:textField name="mobile" id="mobile"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="passwordHash">Password: </label></td>
                <td><g:passwordField name="passwordHash" id="passwordHash"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="passwordHash2">Confirm password: </label></td>
                <td><g:passwordField name="passwordHash2" name="passwordHash2" id="passwordHash2" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><label for="userType">User Type: </label></td>
                <td>
                    <g:radioGroup values="['F','H']" name="userType" labels="['Freelancer','Client']">
                        <p>${ it.radio } ${ it.label }</p>
                    </g:radioGroup>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><g:submitButton name="saveUser" value="Register"/> </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </g:form>
    </div>

</body>
```

maybe there's something wrong in my code?

I want to just show the user an error, but not full exception trace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `save(failOnError:true)` which will cause an exception to be thrown when your save fails.  Since you are only catching the `UserRegistrationException`, the Exception from `save()` is producing a 500 Internal Server Error.  You could remove the `failOnError` and your service method should fall through to your `throw new UserRegistrationException` block and behave as you expect.

Comment: dude, u are my savior. best regards

Answer (score 2):

I just want to add that using Exception for control flow is not good program design and very expensive. I would suggest to remove the `UserRegistrationException` and instead return just a boolean `false` and check for that in the controller. Remember that groovy methods are typed dynamically and you can just return whatever you want.

Comment: The problem with just returning `false` is that you don't know why it failed. So you can return, say, `null` if it passes and a message if it fails. But since `null` is considered "falsey", it feels weird to pass it for success. Alternatively, you can update your exception to _not_ create a stacktrace, which removes a lot of the cost of exceptions. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434431/exception-without-stack-trace-in-java for implementation details.