# Exception without stack trace in Java

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

This is probably a very naive question.

I used to believe that a `Throwable` in Java *always* contains the stack trace. Is it correct?

Now it looks like that I catch exceptions *without* the stack trace. Does it make sense? Is it *possible* to catch an exception without the stack trace?

Comment: What JVM?  Environment? etc.  Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659151/recurring-exception-without-a-stack-trace-how-to-reset

Comment: @SB. Yes, this does help. Thanks a lot. I have a very similar problem: I have a lot of exceptions (NPE). Method `error` of `log4j` logs some exceptions _without_ the stack trace.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It's possible to catch a Throwable object in Java without a stack trace:

```
Throwable(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression,boolean writableStackTrace)
```

> Constructs a new throwable with the
>   specified detail message, cause, suppression enabled or disabled, and
>   **writable stack trace enabled or disabled**.

```
public Throwable fillInStackTrace()
```

> Fills in the execution stack trace. This method records within this
>   Throwable object information about the current state of the stack
>   frames for the current thread.
>
> **If the stack trace of this Throwable is not writable, calling this
>   method has no effect**.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html

Comment: It just says "writeable stack trace" enabled or disabled..
I don't think it means it won't catch the stacktrace

Comment: Does this mean it won't be generated and the process will be a lot faster?

Comment: The documentation for `writableStackTrace` says this: "whether or not the stack trace should be _writable_". Hence that parameter does NOT prevent stack traces from being generated. I don't see how this post answers the question. Please fix or delete this answer!

Comment: Please read the question.  OP is asking if it's possible to catch a `Throwable` without a stack trace.  The answer is of course yes.  Direct quote from documentation for `fillInStackTrace`: "Fills in the execution stack trace. This method records within this Throwable object information about the current state of the stack frames for the current thread.

If the stack trace of this Throwable is not writable, calling this method has no effect."

Answer (score 37):

For Java 6:

As Java 6 doesn't have the `Throwable(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression,boolean writableStackTrace)` constructor, we can suppress the stacktrace filling using below technique (borrowed from Scala, came to know from [How slow are Java exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299068/how-slow-are-java-exceptions))

```
class NoStackTraceRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Usage is same: `throw new NoStackTraceRuntimeException ()`, or it's subtypes.

We can also do the same by extending `Throwable`:

```
class NoStackTraceThrowable extends Throwable {
    @Override
    public synchronized Throwable fillInStackTrace() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

But, a small catch is that you no longer can `catch` these exception using `Exception` as this is not subtype of `Exception`, instead should catch `NoStackTraceThrowable` or it's subtypes.

**Update**: For some interesting stats on performance in different usecases, check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25324557/340290)

Comment: @shekharsuman No, but neither Java 7. This answer might help someone with Java 6 :)

Comment: Even outside of Java 1.6, this is still a viable method. This will suppress the entire stack trace (as the passed in 'cause' of the 4 parameter constructor will be printed out).

Comment: I'm still using Java 6 here in 2016, so yeah :/

Comment: Your `NoStackTraceThrowable` could extend `Exception` instead (and be called `NoStackTraceException`) if you wanted it to be caught by a `catch (Exception)` block.

Comment: There is no need to mark a method merely returning `this` as `synchronized`.

Answer (score 18):

For Java 7+, here is an example of an exception where the stack trace can optionally be suppressed.

```
public class SuppressableStacktraceException extends Exception {

    private boolean suppressStacktrace = false;

    public SuppressableStacktraceException(String message, boolean suppressStacktrace) {
        super(message, null, suppressStacktrace, !suppressStacktrace);
        this.suppressStacktrace = suppressStacktrace;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (suppressStacktrace) {
            return getLocalizedMessage();
        } else {
            return super.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

This can be demonstrated with:

```
try {
    throw new SuppressableStacktraceException("Not suppressed", false);
} catch (SuppressableStacktraceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    throw new SuppressableStacktraceException("Suppressed", true);
} catch (SuppressableStacktraceException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is based on the MLContextException from [Apache SystemML](http://systemml.apache.org/), the code of which is available on GitHub at https://github.com/apache/systemml.

Comment: Neat, removing the toString() still provides me with enough suppression.

Comment: why are you not exposing a contructor arg that would take a throwable?

Comment: Why does supressStackTrace imply supressedException argument in Exception?

Comment: Why do you need to override `toString`?

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way to suppress the stacktrace on any Exception is

```
throwable.setStackTrace(new StackTraceElement[0]);
```

If the exception has a cause, you may need to do the same recursively.

**This also reduces the costly creation of the stack trace, as much as possible**

The stacktrace for a throwable is initialized in

```
Throwable#fillInStackTrace()
```

, which is called by any constructor and thus cannot be avoided.
When the stacktrace actually is used, an StackTraceElement[] is lazily constructed in

```
Throwable#getOurStackTrace()
```

which only happens, if the field Throwable.stackTrace was not already set.

Setting the stacktrace to whatever non null value, avoids the construction of the StackTraceElement[] in  Throwable#getOurStackTrace() and reduces the performance penalty as much as possible.

Comment: This works, but it doesn't solve the problem that most people want to solve by suppressing stack traces. Generating a stack trace is slow, and this can slow down code that uses exceptions a lot for messaging. To address this, one must prevent the creation of the stack traces, not delete them when they have already been created. - That said, your approach could still be useful to save memory when a lot of exceptions over which one has no control are stored for some reason.

Comment: Halo @Hans Adler, I understand your concern, but I think my answer also  reduces the costly creation of the stack trace, as much as possible.Please see my last edit.

Comment: *“[Throwable#fillInStackTrace()] is called by any constructor and thus cannot be avoided.”* – You can override this method in order to make it a no-op.

Answer (score 3):

As hinted at in the reply by NG., if you are seeing the stacktrace at first but then it disappears for the same exception, you are most likely seeing the effects of JVM optimization.
In that case, the following questions are very similar.

[Recurring Exception without a stack trace - how to reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659151/recurring-exception-without-a-stack-trace-how-to-reset)

[NullPointerException in Java with no StackTrace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411487/nullpointerexception-in-java-with-no-stacktrace)

You can turn this JVM feature off, but I would recommend keeping it enabled and working towards preventing the error in the first place, or catching it and handling it more gracefully.